# How to Change show different divs dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am new to javascripting and jquery. I am drawing charts using flot in which i have 2 Bar graphs...

**My first bar graph**

```
<div id="bar1" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
$(function () {

var css_id = "#bar1";
var data = [
    {label: 'foo',color:'red', data: [[1,300], [2,300], [3,300], [4,300], [5,300]]},
    {label: 'bar',color:'blue', data: [[1,800], [2,600], [3,400], [4,200], [5,0]]},
    {label: 'baz',color:'green', data: [[1,100], [2,200], [3,300], [4,400], [5,500]]},
];
var options = {
    series: {stack: 0,
             lines: {show: false, steps: false },
             bars: {show: true, barWidth: 0.4, align: 'center',},},
    xaxis: {ticks: [[1,'One'], [2,'Two'], [3,'Three'], [4,'Four'], [5,'Five']]},
};

$.plot($(css_id), data, options);

});​
```

**My second graph**

```
<div id="bar2" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
var data = [
    {label: 'foo', color:'red', data: [[1,300], [2,300], [3,300], [4,300], [5,300]]},
    {label: 'bar', color:'blue', data: [[1,800], [2,600], [3,400], [4,200], [5,0]]},
    {label: 'baz', color:'yellow', data: [[1,100], [2,200], [3,300], [4,400],   [5,500]]},
    ];

$.plot($("#bar2"), data, {
series: {
    stack: 1,
    bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 0.6,
        fill:1
    }
}
});​
```

**Now i have a click event of a button**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
......
});
```

Now what should i write on the occurance of the button event such that i dynamically change my bar graphs from `<div id="bar1">` to `<div id="bar2">`

Comment: _Now what should i write on the occurance of the button event such that i dynamically change my bar graphs from to..._ <--??

Comment: Hide one div with $('#bar1').hide() and show the other $('#bar2').show() or vice versa if you're trying to show the other one.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I'd definitely recommend you read through the jQuery documentation. Would also encourage you to post only the relevant information along with exactly what @JonathanM mentioned - what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly you want to hide/show each div on the press of a button .... first hide one of the `<div>` using `style="display:none"` and then use the following code to toggle both on `click` of a button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#idofbutton').click(function() {
      $('#bar1,#bar2').toggle();
   });
});
```

Using `toggle()` on both with hide the currently shown `div` and show the currently hidden `div` (hope that makes sense !)

[Docs for toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: nice. haven't seen this used this way.  Learn something new everyday on SO. +1

Answer (score 0):

Set the css for `#bar2` to `display:none`

```
var toggle = true;
$("#button").click(function()
{
    if(toggle)
    {
        $("#bar1").hide();
        $("#bar2").show();
        toggle = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#bar1").show();
        $("#bar2").hide();
        toggle = true;
    }

});
```